# If I send message to someone or someone message me i want to display the names like messenger of distinct users order by id desc

Tags: mysql, distinct-values

If I send message or someone message to me I want to display the names of distinct user in list order by id desc other than me

```
$resl_msg1 = mysqli_query($connection,"select ruid  from messenger where uid = '".$_SESSION['id']."' union select uid from messenger where ruid = '".$_SESSION['id']."'  " );


$resl_msg1 = mysqli_query($connection,"select ruid  from messenger where uid = '".$_SESSION['id']."' union select uid from messenger where ruid = '".$_SESSION['id']."'  " );
            i want to get the distinct users order by id desc
```

Comment: I'm not sure I've git your issue: You get all the data you need in your statement you just want to order the result off the union select by id (i.e. `ruid` and `uid`)?

Comment: HA YES I AM GETTING IN ASC I WANT TO GET IN DESC

Comment: Just use `select ruid as id from messenger where uid = '".$_SESSION['id']."' union select uid as id from messenger where ruid = '".$_SESSION['id']."' order by id desc`

Comment: Unknown column 'id' in 'order clause'